# Django Python 3.* : Reverse for 'view' not found

Tags: python-3.x, django-views, django-urls, django-3.0, django-url-reverse

I have a **first_view** that takes **id** argument, And **second_view** that redirects to **first_view** after interpreting some code.

**views.py**:

```
def first_view(request, id):
    #do something
    return render(request, 'sometemplate.html')

def second_view(request, id):
    #do something
    return redirect('first_view', id=id)
```

when I try to go through **second_view** I get this error:

> Reverse for 'first_view' not found.

**urls.py:**

```
    path('first_view/<int:pnr_id>/', views.first_view, name='first_view'),
    path('second_view/<int:pnr_id>/', views.second_view, name='second_view'),
```

I've tried these syntax for redirect too:

1. `return redirect('first_view', id)`
2. `return redirect('first_view', args=[id])`
3. `return redirect('first_view', args=[id=id])`
4. `return redirect(first_view(id=id))`
5. `return redirect(first_view(id))`
6. `return redirect(first_view(request=request,id=id))`
7. `return redirect(first_view(request,id))`

Nothing works! any support will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the issue to save your time..

when you call `redirect()` make sure that you are passing the *url name* not the *view def name*